# Custom Validation with custom form control in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I created app-input component to show input textbox.

I am not able to apply custom form validation.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you post more info? What have you tried? Can you post a stackblitz example with your code?

Comment: Please provide more code from your template and component ts file.

Comment: You tried... Okay.... But where is the code of your try??

Answer (score 4):

Since example is not given in clarification, lets assume you have to post a Form to capture imaginary Account. The AccountService is making HTTP post to API.

My custom Validator name is accountIdValidator where it expects the account Id to start with 123.

Refer the code below

```js
In Componenet TS
--------------------
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, AbstractControl, FormBuilder, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-survey-child',
  templateUrl: './survey-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./survey-child.component.css']
})
export class SurveyChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() surveyChildValue: string;
  public testValue: string;
  
  dealForm: FormGroup;
  dealName: AbstractControl;
  accountShortName = '';
  accountId = '';
  dealId = 0;
  isLoadingResults = false;

  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

  constructor(private router: Router, private api: AccountService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.dealForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'accountName': [null, Validators.required],
      'accountShortName': [null, null],
      'accountId': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, accountIdValidator])]
    });
    console.log('initialize account add');
    this.dealName = this.dealForm.controls['dealName'];

    this.dealName.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
      console.log('deal name changed to:', value);
    });

    this.dealForm.valueChanges.subscribe((form: any) => {
      console.log('form changed to:', form);
    });
  }



  onFormSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.api.addAccount(form)
      .subscribe((res: { [x: string]: any; }) => {
        const response = res;
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
        //  this.router.navigate(['/account-details', id]);
        console.log('Account added succesfully: ' + response);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error: Account Add :  ' + err);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      });
  }


}

//Custom Validations
function accountIdValidator(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
  if (!control.value.match(/^123/)) {
    //should start with 123
    return { invalidAccountId: true };
  }
}


/** Error when invalid control is dirty, touched, or submitted. */
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }
}
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <!--<div class="button-row">
    <a mat-flat-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['/accounts']"><mat-icon>list</mat-icon></a>
  </div>-->
  <mat-card class="example-card">
    <form [formGroup]="dealForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(dealForm.value)">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Deal Name" formControlName="dealName" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" id="dealNameInput">
        <mat-error>
          <span *ngIf="!dealForm.get('dealName').valid && dealForm.get('dealName').touched">Please enter valid Deal Name</span>
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Account Name" formControlName="accountShortName" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Account Id" formControlName="accountId" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
      </mat-form-field>

      <div class="button-row">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!dealForm.valid" mat-flat-button color="primary"><mat-icon>Save</mat-icon></button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```